# Oracle DB ORA-26804: Apply xstream is disabled

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracleclient, oracle-golden-gate

I'm connecting to Oracle DB through a XStream Out Server and I'm getting this error after a minute or two attaching:

```
ORA-26804: Apply "XSTREAM_OUT1" is disabled.
ORA-31020: The operation is not allowed, Reason: not in a valid apply process
```

What is causing this error? I can see my service is attached to the XStream Out Server by checking the DB with this query:

```
select CLIENT_NAME, CLIENT_STATUS from dba_capture
```

Comment: Did you tried monitoring as suggested here : http://oradb-srv.wlv.ac.uk/E50529_01/XSTRM/xstrm_xout_mon.htm#XSTRM1439

ORA-26804 means the process is aborted. Would be useful to see as what is causing abortion

Comment: Thanks. That's a step in the right direction. Can you post the query snippets as an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 0):

Below link helped to debug the cause :
http://oradb-srv.wlv.ac.uk/E50529_01/XSTRM/xstrm_xout_mon.htm#XSTRM1439

> Additional info : ORA-26804 means the process is aborted.